# How can I get Mathematica to simplify $\Vert\{1,\sin(t),\cos(t)\}\Vert_2$ to $\sqrt{2}$?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

### Context

```
Norm[{1, Sin[t], Cos[t]}]
Norm[{1, Sin[t], Cos[t]}] // Simplify
(*
Sqrt[1 + Abs[Cos[t]]^2 + Abs[Sin[t]]^2]    
Sqrt[1 + Abs[Cos[t]]^2 + Abs[Sin[t]]^2]
*)
```

### Question:

How do I coax *Mathematica* to output `Sqrt[2]`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
Simplify[Norm[{1, Sin[t], Cos[t]}], Element[t, Reals]]
(*
 Sqrt[2]
*)
```

Because

```
Plot3D[Norm[{1, Sin[a + b I], Cos[a + b I]}], {a, -1, 1}, {b, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: so basically, the problem is that Mathematica is smarter than me, and I was not aware that cos^2 x + sin^2 x = 1 only for real x ?

Comment: @term-rewritica: no, you are right $\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x$ is always 1. However $|\cos x|^2+ | \sin x|^2$ is not always equal to 1.

Comment: @belisarius Wow, this was elegantly done!

Answer (score 11):

Just so that all the i's are dotted and t's crossed:

$$\cos^2(z)+\sin^2(z)=1$$ for all complex $z$ (since $\cos^2(z)+\sin^2(z)-1$ is
a holomorphic function that vanishes on the real axis, it vanishes everywhere);
but $$|\cos(z)|^2+|\sin(z)|^2 \neq 1$$ in general unless $z$ is real.